# Input box appears, but nothing happens when you click

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I'm using the bootstrap library **bootsrap-select** to create a custom input component that behaves like a  element (
I needed the *live research*, for example).
I entered the right dependencies in **angular.json**:

```
"scripts": [ 
              "./node_modules/path-to-files/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"
           ]
```

The problem is that if I insert simple code, like this:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-width="250px" data-live-search="true" 
        title="Select the right value" data-size="10">
    <option value="a">Value 1</option>
    <option value="b">Value 2</option>
    <option value="c">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that the input box appears, but nothing happens when you click on it!
[image]

How can I enable all features using Angular with TypeScript (without pure JavaScript )?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you also include the other [dependencies](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) (jQuery, Bootstrap dropdown.js, Bootstrap CSS) in your Angular project?

Comment: Thanks!!! I had not added dropdown.js dependency!

Comment: Use `$('.select').selectpicker();` as first line in onInit method.

Answer (score 4):

You can install bootstrap-select types from typeDefinition. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap-select

**Step1 :**

declare var $:any;

**Step2:**

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

// Angular way of doing.

**Template:**

```
<select #selectdp class="form-control selectpicker" data-width="250px" data-live-search="true" 
        title="Select the right value" data-size="10">
    <option value="a">Value 1</option>
    <option value="b">Value 2</option>
    <option value="c">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

**Component:**

```
@ViewChild('selectdp') selectdp: ElementRef;
this.selectdp.nativeElement.selectpicker('refresh');
```

Check whether this below URL helps. [bootstrap-select dropdown options not getting loaded sometime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807711/bootstrap-select-dropdown-options-not-getting-loaded-sometime)

Also make sure you have jquery and @types are installed as dependencies.

Comment: Could you please add a `ViewChild` implementation of this instead of using jQuery?

Comment: Updated Angular implementation sidd.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya why should I install bootstrap-select types? I have already installted bootstrap-select