# Angular: bootstrap fails to trigger select option as options are dynamically binded using ngFor

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular7

I have a select list that is dynamically loaded in my component and the select list has bootstrap applied but initially when bootstrap runs it doesn't find any options in select and hence fails to apply on the select list.

I tried the solution provided here 
[bootstrap-select dropdown options not getting loaded sometime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807711/bootstrap-select-dropdown-options-not-getting-loaded-sometime)

but of no help.

Component **Html**:

```
<div class="hero-image-bedrooms form-group">
    <select class="form-control" title="Bedrooms" id="selectbedroom">
        <option class="bs-title-option" value="">Select Bedroom</option>
       <option *ngFor="let keys of bedroommstkey" 
        value="{{bedroommst[keys].bedroomsid}}">{{bedroommst[keys].bedrooms}}</option> 
      </select>
</div>
```

Loading **json**:

[
      {
       "bedroomsid": "1",
       "bedrooms": "Studio Apt"
     },
     {
       "bedroomsid": "2",
       "bedrooms": "1 BHK"
     },
     {
       "bedroomsid": "3",
       "bedrooms": "2 BHK"
     },
     {
       "bedroomsid": "4",
       "bedrooms": "3 BHK"
     },
     {
       "bedroomsid": "5",
       "bedrooms": "4 BHK"
     },
     {
       "bedroomsid": "6",
       "bedrooms": "5 BHK"
     },
     {
       "bedroomsid": "7",
       "bedrooms": "6 BHK"
     },
     {
       "bedroomsid": "8",
       "bedrooms": "7 BHK"
     },
     {
       "bedroomsid": "9",
       "bedrooms": "8 BHK"
     },
     {
       "bedroomsid": "10",
       "bedrooms": "9 BHK"
     }
   ]

The **Generated HTML**:

```
<select _ngcontent-why-c1="" class="form-control bs-select-hidden" id="selectbedroom" title="Bedrooms">
<option _ngcontent-why-c1="" class="bs-title-option" value="" ng-reflect-     value="">Select Bedroom</option><!--bindings={
 "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
  }-->
 <option _ngcontent-why-c1="" value="1" ng-reflect-value="1">Studio    Apt</option>
 <option _ngcontent-why-c1="" value="2" ng-reflect-value="2">1 BHK</option>
 <option _ngcontent-why-c1="" value="3" ng-reflect-value="3">2 BHK</option>
 <option _ngcontent-why-c1="" value="4" ng-reflect-value="4">3 BHK</option>
 <option _ngcontent-why-c1="" value="5" ng-reflect-value="5">4 BHK</option>
 <option _ngcontent-why-c1="" value="6" ng-reflect-value="6">5 BHK</option>
 <option _ngcontent-why-c1="" value="7" ng-reflect-value="7">6 BHK</option>
 <option _ngcontent-why-c1="" value="8" ng-reflect-value="8">7 BHK</option>
 <option _ngcontent-why-c1="" value="9" ng-reflect-value="9">8 BHK</option>
 <option _ngcontent-why-c1="" value="10" ng-reflect-value="10">9 BHK</option>
 </select>
 <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control open">
 <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="selectbedroom" title="Select Bedroom" aria-expanded="true">
 <span class="filter-option pull-left">Select Bedroom</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret">
 </span>
 </button>
 <div class="dropdown-backdrop"></div>
 <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 139.917px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px;">
 <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="max-height: 137.917px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;">       
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

As in the generated Html the ul li generated doesn't have the dynamic items listed in the select options.

Please help with a appropriate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem** was 
`<option *ngFor="let keys of bedroommstkey" value="{{bedroommst[keys].bedroomsid}}">{{bedroommst[keys].bedrooms}}</option>`

**should** have been (keeping in view that you're probably getting this json from a service);
`<option *ngFor="let keys of bedroommstkey" value="{{keys?.bedroomsid}}">{{keys?.bedrooms}}</option>`

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class="hero-image-bedrooms form-group">
  <div *ngIf="bedroommstkey.length>0">
    <select class="form-control" title="Bedrooms" id="selectbedroom">
        <option class="bs-title-option" value="">Select Bedroom</option>
       <option *ngFor="let keys of bedroommstkey" 
        value="{{keys?.bedroomsid}}">{{keys?.bedrooms}}</option> 
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
  bedroommstkey = [ { "bedroomsid": "1", "bedrooms": "Studio Apt" }, { "bedroomsid": "2", "bedrooms": "1 BHK" }, { "bedroomsid": "3", "bedrooms": "2 BHK" }, { "bedroomsid": "4", "bedrooms": "3 BHK" }, { "bedroomsid": "5", "bedrooms": "4 BHK" }, { "bedroomsid": "6", "bedrooms": "5 BHK" }, { "bedroomsid": "7", "bedrooms": "6 BHK" }, { "bedroomsid": "8", "bedrooms": "7 BHK" }, { "bedroomsid": "9", "bedrooms": "8 BHK" }, { "bedroomsid": "10", "bedrooms": "9 BHK" } ];
```

simple [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvfxcf)